# CUDA shared memory more than 1 block stops working

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I am writing a program for school using shared memory. I got the function to work correctly, yet it only works with a single block per grid. If there is more than one block per grid then the function no longer works.

For example, If I send in an array of size 10, with 1 block and 10 threads this function works correctly. If I send in the same array with 2 blocks and 5 threads per block then it no longer works. When I say no longer works, I am getting the same array I sent in, back out, like nothing is happening.

```
__global__ void rankSortShared(int* a, int n)
{
    int threadId = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int x = 0;

    // Make dynamic sized shared array
    // size will be determined from the 3rd parameter in the 
    // kernal call 'ranksortShared<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock, *(size of shared mem)*>>>()'
    extern __shared__ int b[];

    // copy data from incomming array to shared array
    // then sync the threads so all threads have put their 
    // values into the shared array
    b[threadId] = a[threadId];
    __syncthreads();

    // now use shared array for faster lookups
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        // handle duplicate values
        if (b[j] < b[threadId] || (b[threadId] == b[j] && j < threadId))
        {
            x++;
        }   
    }
    // put data back into array to be transferred back to CPU
    a[x] = b[threadId];
}
```

For the life of me I can not figure out why. Is there a special way to use shared memory across multiple blocks?

Just to try and debug this, I replaced all the code with `a[threadId] = threadId` and the array was seemingly correct (printing the numbers 0 through 9). So then I do not understand why this wouldn't work if the `threadId`s seem to be correct, and it works with one block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem here:

```
int threadId = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
b[threadId] = ...;
```

Your `threadId` variable is a globally unique thread index.  That means the more threads you include in the grid (e.g. via more blocks), the higher this index will go.

But for shared memory, the index *in each block* starts at zero.  So eventually, as you add more blocks, your `threadId` variable will be larger than the amount of shared memory in a block.

The usual solution is to do something like this:

```
b[threadIdx.x] = ...;
```

since the `threadIdx.x` variable starts at zero *in each block*.  (You would replace **every** occurrence of `b[threadId]` with `b[threadIdx.x]` using this strategy, not just one occurrence.)

There may well be other problems in your code.  Since you haven't shown a complete code, it's not possible to diagnose others.

And based on statements like this:

> When I say no longer works, I am getting the same array I sent in, back out, like nothing is happening.

my guess is you are not doing [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).  You should really be doing that *before* asking for help from others.  Even if you don't understand the error output, it will help others trying to help you.